# Does sync mode matter for TxPool monitoring?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, txpool

I'm planning on setting up a Geth Node to monitor the txpool.

I know that more nodes spread out geographically means you will receive new transactions quicker, but does the sync mode have an effect?